# TensorFlow 2.0 returns unexpected output on dtype=int32 with GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow

The following code should output the gradient of y=x*x for x=2, i.e. the value of 4. However the code prints a value of None when using TensorFlow 2.0.0-alpha0. When the definition of x changes to use `tf.float32` instead of `tf.int32` as shown in the next snippet, the output changes to the correct value of 4. Is there any documentation that clarifies the requirement for the data type to be a floating point number for GradientTape to work correctly in this scenario?

```py
print(tf.__version__)

x = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  tape.watch(x)
  y = x ** 2
  print(tape.gradient(y, x))
```

outputs:

```
2.0.0-alpha0
None
```

Notice the change to `tf.float32` in the next snippet:

```py
print(tf.__version__)

x = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  tape.watch(x)
  y = x ** 2
  print(tape.gradient(y, x))
```

outputs:

```
2.0.0-alpha0
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `tf.gradient` doesn't propagate the gradients through integer tensors. This has been referenced in this github issue:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524